# Possible root cause for mix ecto.migrate resulting in recv failed timeout

Tags: erlang, elixir, ecto, elixir-mix

I am new to Elixir/Erlang. As I need to setup an existing application, I am executing below step to generate migrations:

```
mix ecto.migrate
```

After migrating 9 tables, everytime it is throwing following error:

```
<b> 00:55:30.074 [error] Mariaex.Protocol (#PID<0.415.0>) disconnected: ** (Mariaex.Error) [tcp] `recv` failed with: :timeout </b>
```

I am really stuck here and do not know how to move ahead. Theare are around 175 migration files.

I tried to re-run the migrations command but that is not working.

Comment: Are you able to paste the code of the migration which is causing timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the migration whos generate this error performs a long operation and exceeds your MariaDB/MySQL timeout.

Try increase your timeouts for this operation:

- https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-shared-options